# Apache 'Directory Alias' not working in vagrant Homestead

Tags: apache, vagrant, homestead, mod-alias

In attempting to replicate our production servers on my local machine I have created a 'Directory Alias' in Homestead's VirtualHost conf. However, regardles of the many settings I try from various Stackoverflow posts, I keep getting the same 404 not found response in the browser. Hoping someone can help me troubleshoot this?

In Homestead I have swapped Nginx for Apache and restructured the location of the server root and project files to match our production servers. Here is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/johno/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk
      to: /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk

sites:
    - map: homestead.client1.co.uk
      to: /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/public
      type: apache

databases:
    - project_two

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And here is my vhosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName homestead.client1.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.homestead.client1.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/public

    <Directory /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

# code added

        Alias /project-one /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/public
        <Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/public">
            Options None
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

# code added

    <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        AddHandler php7.3-fcgi .php
        Action php7.3-fcgi /php7.3-fcgi
        Alias /php7.3-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.3
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.3 -socket /var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
        <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
            <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
                SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
            </FilesMatch>
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/homestead.client1.co.uk-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/homestead.client1.co.uk-access.log combined

    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

The only amend I have made to the vhost is the addtion of code between `# code added`.

I've placed an `index.php` file in the server root displaying `phpinfo();`:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls -la /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/public/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  96 Sep  8 05:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 160 Sep  8 05:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant  17 Sep  7 05:10 index.php
```

In the browser I can visit `http://homestead.client1.co.uk/index.php` and successfully see the output of this, so the server is working fine.

However, if I request the 'Alias' directory using `http://homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/index.php` I recieve a 404 not found response.

I can confirm the project files are in the location specified in the vhost alias and the permissions are set correctly:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls -la /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/public/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   192 Sep  7 06:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    96 Sep  7 06:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    96 Sep  7 06:41 css
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant   480 Sep  7 06:41 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 24679 Sep  7 06:40 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    96 Sep  7 06:40 libs
```

As you can see , 'project-one' is NOT a laravel framework, it is a simple static landing page for testing purposes.

Any help troubleshooting would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does error log show anything?
Can you try adding `Require All Granted` under project-one alias like below:

```
Alias /project-one /srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/public
<Directory "/srv/www/vhosts/homestead.client1.co.uk/project-one/public">
      Options None
      AllowOverride All
      Order Deny,Allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: you are a legend! That worked perfectly, thank you so much :-) I don't seem to have an option to accept your answer as the solution but I will try to find a way... clearly I need to learn/understand more about these configurations, I suppose the Apache documentation is the best place? Any other reccommedations?

Comment: Glad it worked :) You may find these very helpful:
https://serverfault.com/a/549559
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/what-does-require-all-granted-do-4175505357/